# Can ListView host TextView items that are also displayed in a separate TextView

Tags: java, android, listview, android-studio, textview

I'm having a problem changing a TextView to a ListView.  Originally, the app had a button that when clicked, runs tests to a bluetooth device and displays the results in a textview.  I modified the app to contain two textviews that have the last text results and a separate xml file (connected with viewflipper) to go to a second textview that contains all of the test results, until the user clears the textview by clicking a button.  I followed along with [this example](http://abhiandroid.com/ui/listview) and checked what I was entering in the ArrayAdapter section of the code, and it appears to be what is required according to the [developer's guide](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html), but I still get his error:

Cannot resolve constructor 'ArrayAdapter(com.example.android.stardustscanner.ScannerFragment, int, int, java.lang.String)'

Why am I getting this error?

My .java file that I am making all the changes in is very long and contains a lot of thins that aren't relevant to this question and doesn't fit in the question box, so I'll try to only include the relevant parts.  The error is towards the bottom with this line:
`ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.fragment_bluetooth_scanner, R.id.textView, saveData);`

ScannerFragment.java

```
public class ScannerFragment extends Fragment implements LocationListener {

    ListView mListView;




    //page switching things KG 8/24/17
    private ViewFlipper mViewFlipper;
    private float lastX;
    private Button mViewLog;
    private Button mReturnFlipper;
    private TextView mShowData;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }



    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container,
                             @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.flipper_holder, container, false);//kg 8/24/17
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        SP = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getContext());

        mViewFlipper = (ViewFlipper) view.findViewById(R.id.viewFlip); //KG 8/24/17
        mViewLog = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.viewLog); //kg 8/24/17
        mReturnFlipper = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.flipperReturn); //kg 8/24/17
        mShowData = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView) ; //kg 8/25/2017
        mShowData.setText(readFromFile()); // kg 8/25/2017

        mPowerOffButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button_poweroff);
        mDisconnectButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button_disconnect);
        mConnectButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button_connect);
        mPresence = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button_present);

        mBattery = (ProgressBar) view.findViewById(R.id.progressBar);

        mBlinkConnect = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button_connectionblink);
        mBlinkData = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button_communication);
        mClearLog = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button_clear_log);

        mDeviceName = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button_devicename);
        mDeviceSN = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button_devicesn);
        mBatteryPerc = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.label_batterypct);

        mListView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.scanLogView); //kg 8/28/17

        // mReadingLog  = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.scanLogView);
        mReadingLog.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
        mReadingLog.setText(readFromFile());

        telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager)getContext().getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

        initLocationService(this.getContext());

        final ActionBar actionBar = getActivity().getActionBar();
        if (null == actionBar) {
            return;
        }
        final Drawable D = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.stardust2);
        actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(D);
        actionBar.setTitle("");

        //KG 8/24/17
        mViewLog.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view){
                mViewFlipper.showNext();
            }
        });

        mReturnFlipper.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view){
                mViewFlipper.showPrevious();
            }
        });

    }

    private void setupScanner() {
        Log.d(TAG, "setupScanner()");

        // Initialize the send button with a listener that for click events
        mPowerOffButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(isIris) {
                    publishMessage(Constants.COMMAND_POWEROFF_IRIS);
                } else {
                    publishMessage(Constants.COMMAND_POWEROFF);
                }
                mScannerService.stop();
            }
        });

        // Initialize the send button with a listener that for click events
        mDisconnectButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Send a message using content of the edit text widget
                publishMessage(Constants.COMMAND_DISCONNECT);
                mScannerService.stop();
            }
        });

        // Initialize the send button with a listener that for click events
        mConnectButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Send a message using content of the edit text widget
                publishMessage(Constants.COMMAND_ON_CONNECT);
            }
        });

        mClearLog.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Send a message using content of the edit text widget
                mReadingLog.setText("");
                if(SP.getBoolean("writeToFile", true)) {
                    writeToFile("", "", false);
                }
            }
        });


        // Initialize the ScannerService to perform bluetooth connections
        mScannerService = new ScannerService(getActivity(), mHandler);
    }

    private TextView.OnEditorActionListener mWriteListener
            = new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView view, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
            // If the action is a key-up event on the return key, send the message
            if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_NULL && event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                String message = view.getText().toString();
                publishMessage(message);
            }
            return true;
        }
    };


    private final Handler mHandler = new Handler() {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            FragmentActivity activity = getActivity();
            switch (msg.what) {
                case Constants.MESSAGE_STATE_CHANGE:
                    switch (msg.arg1) {
                        case ScannerService.STATE_CONNECTED:
                            setStatus(mConnectedDeviceName);

                            if(mConnectedDeviceName.substring(0, 4).toLowerCase().equals("iris") || mConnectedDeviceName.substring(0, 8).toLowerCase().equals("stardust")) {
                                isIris = true;

                                mPresence.setClickable(true);
                                mPresence.setText("Click to detect taggant");
                                mPresence.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#0061ff"));

                                mPresence.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                    public void onClick(View v) {
                                        readoutStarted = true;
                                        publishMessage(Constants.COMMAND_RUN_IRIS);
                                    }
                                });

                                mPowerOffButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                    public void onClick(View v) {
                                        publishMessage(Constants.COMMAND_POWEROFF_IRIS);
                                        mScannerService.stop();
                                    }
                                });
                            } else {
                                isIris = false;
                            }

                            if(!isIris) {
                                mPresence.setClickable(false);
                                mPresence.setText("NO TAGGANT DETECTED");
                                mPresence.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ffc4ab"));

                                publishMessage(Constants.COMMAND_ON_CONNECT);

                                timer = new Timer();
                                timerStarted = true;
                                timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {

                                    synchronized public void run() {
                                        publishMessage(Constants.COMMAND_READDATA);
                                    }

                                }, 1000, 1000);
                            } else {
                                if(timerStarted) {
                                    timer.cancel();
                                    timer.purge();
                                    timerStarted = false;
                                }
                            }
                            mBlinkConnect.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#11D901"));
                            break;
                        case ScannerService.STATE_CONNECTING:
                            setStatus("C");
                            break;
                        case ScannerService.STATE_LISTEN:
                        case ScannerService.STATE_NONE:
                            mBlinkConnect.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ff2b0f"));
                            mBlinkData.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#CCCCCC"));
                            if(timerStarted) {
                                timer.cancel();
                                timer.purge();
                                timerStarted = false;
                            }
                            setStatus("D");
                            break;
                    }
                    break;
                case Constants.MESSAGE_WRITE:
                    mBlinkData.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#CCCCCC"));

                    break;
                case Constants.MESSAGE_READ:
                    mBlinkData.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#0091FA"));

                    String readMessage = (String)msg.obj;

                    if(isIris) {
                        readIris(readMessage);
                    } else {
                        readNormal(readMessage);
                    }

                    break;
                case Constants.MESSAGE_DEVICE_NAME:
                    // save the connected device's name
                    mConnectedDeviceName = msg.getData().getString(Constants.DEVICE_NAME);
                    if (null != activity) {
                        Toast.makeText(activity, "Connected to "
                                + mConnectedDeviceName, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    break;
                case Constants.MESSAGE_TOAST:
                    if (null != activity) {
                        Toast.makeText(activity, msg.getData().getString(Constants.TOAST),
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }
    };

    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case REQUEST_CONNECT_DEVICE_SECURE:
                // When DeviceListActivity returns with a device to connect
                if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                    connectDevice(data, true);
                }
                break;
            case REQUEST_CONNECT_DEVICE_INSECURE:
                // When DeviceListActivity returns with a device to connect
                if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                    connectDevice(data, false);
                }
                break;
            case REQUEST_ENABLE_BT:
                // When the request to enable Bluetooth returns
                if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                    // Bluetooth is now enabled, so set up a session
                    setupScanner();
                } else {
                    // User did not enable Bluetooth or an error occurred
                    Log.d(TAG, "BT not enabled");
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), R.string.bt_not_enabled_leaving,
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    getActivity().finish();
                }
        }
    }





    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.secure_connect_scan: {
                // Launch the DeviceListActivity to see devices and do scan
                Intent serverIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), DeviceListActivity.class);
                startActivityForResult(serverIntent, REQUEST_CONNECT_DEVICE_SECURE);
                return true;
            }
            /*case R.id.insecure_connect_scan: {
                // Launch the DeviceListActivity to see devices and do scan
                Intent serverIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), DeviceListActivity.class);
                startActivityForResult(serverIntent, REQUEST_CONNECT_DEVICE_INSECURE);
                return true;
            }*/
            case R.id.settings_button: {
                Intent serverIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), SettingsActivity.class);
                startActivityForResult(serverIntent, REQUEST_SHOW_SETTINGS);
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param data String
     * @param append boolean
     */
    private void writeToFile(String data, String uploadData, boolean append) {
        String root = Environment
                .getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
        File myDir = new File(root);
        String fname = "starDust.txt";
        String fname2 = "starDust.csv";
        File file = new File (myDir, fname);
        File file2 = new File (myDir, fname2);
        //if (file.exists ()) file.delete ();
        try {
            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file, append);
            out.write(data.getBytes(), 0, data.getBytes().length);
            out.flush();
            out.close();

            FileOutputStream out2 = new FileOutputStream(file2, append);
            out2.write(uploadData.getBytes(), 0, uploadData.getBytes().length);
            out2.flush();
            out2.close();

            if(mConnectedDeviceName != null) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Connecting " + SP.getString("server_ip", "") + SP.getString("server_username", "") + SP.getString("server_password", ""));
                new FTPUploadTask().execute(mConnectedDeviceName, SP.getString("server_ip", ""), SP.getString("server_username", "") , SP.getString("server_password", ""));
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     *
     */
    private String readFromFile() {
        String root = Environment
                .getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
        File myDir = new File(root);
        String fname = "starDust.txt";
        File file = new File (myDir, fname);
        StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();

        if (file.exists ()) {
            try {
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
                String line;

                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    text.insert(0, line + System.getProperty("line.separator"));
                }
                br.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {

            }
        }

        return text.toString();

    }


    private void readNormal(String readMessage) {
        String parsedData[];

        if(readMessage.contains(";")) {

            if(readMessage.equals(";")) {
                parsedData = bufferedMessage.trim().split(",");
                bufferedMessage = "";
            } else {
                String partialMessage[] = readMessage.split(";");
                bufferedMessage += partialMessage[0];
                parsedData = bufferedMessage.trim().split(",");

                if (partialMessage.length > 1) {
                    bufferedMessage = partialMessage[1];
                } else {
                    bufferedMessage = "";
                }
            }
        } else {
            bufferedMessage += readMessage.trim();
            return;
        }

        if(parsedData.length == RESPONSE_SIZE && parsedData[0].equals("U")) {
            if(parsedData[1].matches("[-+]?\\d*\\.?\\d+")) {
                if(Integer.parseInt(parsedData[1]) > maxU1 || hitTrigger) {
                    maxU1 = Integer.parseInt(parsedData[1]);
                }
            }
            if(parsedData[2].matches("[-+]?\\d*\\.?\\d+")) {
                if(Integer.parseInt(parsedData[2]) > maxU2 || hitTrigger) {
                    maxU2 = Integer.parseInt(parsedData[2]);
                }
            }
            if(parsedData[3].matches("[-+]?\\d*\\.?\\d+")) {
                if(Integer.parseInt(parsedData[3]) > maxU3 || hitTrigger) {
                    maxU3 = Integer.parseInt(parsedData[3]);
                }
            }

            double u1val = Double.parseDouble(parsedData[1]);
            double u2val = Double.parseDouble(parsedData[2]);
            double u1u2div = 0;

            if(u2val > 0) {
                u1u2div = ((u1val / u2val) * KFactor);
            }

            if(parsedData[4].matches("[-+]?\\d*\\.?\\d+")) {
                mBatteryPerc.setText(parsedData[4] + "%");
                mBattery.setProgress(Integer.parseInt(parsedData[4]));
            }
        }

        taggantType = 0;

        if(maxU1 > Integer.parseInt(SP.getString("maxThreshold", Integer.toString(MAX_TRIGGER)))) {
            taggantType += 4;
        } else {
            taggantType += 0;
        }

        if(maxU2 > Integer.parseInt(SP.getString("maxThreshold", Integer.toString(MAX_TRIGGER)))) {
            taggantType += 2;
        } else {
            taggantType += 0;
        }

        if(maxU3 > Integer.parseInt(SP.getString("maxThreshold", Integer.toString(MAX_TRIGGER)))) {
            taggantType += 1;
        } else {
            taggantType += 0;
        }

        Log.d(TAG, Integer.toString(taggantType));
        Log.d(TAG, Boolean.toString(hitTrigger));
        Log.d(TAG, bufferedMessage);

        // Check if hit threshold, if so hitTrigger is enabled.
        if(taggantType > 0) {
            savedTaggantType = taggantType;
            hitTrigger = true;
            mPresence.setText("VALID TAGGANT DETECTED");
            mPresence.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#11D901"));
        }  else if(taggantType == 0 && hitTrigger) {
            hitTrigger = false;
            mPresence.setText("NO TAGGANT DETECTED");
            mPresence.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ffc4ab"));

            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
            String currentDateandTime = sdf.format(new Date());
            String saveData =
                    "Device: " + mConnectedDeviceName +
                            System.getProperty("line.separator") +
                            "Timestamp: " + currentDateandTime +
                            System.getProperty("line.separator") +
                            "Location: " + latitude + " (lat) / " + longitude + " (lon)" +
                            System.getProperty("line.separator") +
                            "Taggan Type: N" + Integer.toString(savedTaggantType) +
                            System.getProperty("line.separator") +
                            "Phone id: "  + telephonyManager.getDeviceId() +
                            System.getProperty("line.separator") +
                            "=========================" +
                            System.getProperty("line.separator");

            String csvData = mConnectedDeviceName + "," +
                    currentDateandTime + "," +
                    "\"http://maps.google.com/?q=" + latitude + "," + longitude + "\"," +
                    "N" + Integer.toString(savedTaggantType) + "," +
                    "\"" + telephonyManager.getDeviceId() + "\"" +
                    System.getProperty("line.separator");

            mReadingLog.setText(saveData + mReadingLog.getText());
            mShowData.setText(saveData); //kg 8/25/17

            maxU1 = 0;
            maxU2 = 0;
            maxU3 = 0;
            savedTaggantType = 0;

            if(SP.getBoolean("writeToFile", true)) {
                writeToFile(saveData, csvData, true);
            }
        }

    }

    /**
     * @param readMessage String
     */
    public void readIris(String readMessage) {
        if(!readoutStarted) {
            return;
        }

        String parsedData[];

        if(readMessage.contains(";")) {
            readoutStarted = false;
            if(readMessage.equals(";")) {
                parsedData = bufferedMessage.replaceAll("\n", "").replaceAll(" +", " ").trim().split("\\*");
                bufferedMessage = "";
            } else {
                String partialMessage[] = readMessage.replaceAll("\n", "").replaceAll(" +", " ").trim().split(";");
                bufferedMessage += partialMessage[0].trim();
                parsedData = bufferedMessage.replaceAll("\n", "").replaceAll(" +", " ").trim().split("\\*");
                bufferedMessage = "";
            }
        } else {
            bufferedMessage += readMessage.trim().replaceAll("\n", "").replaceAll(" +", " ");
            return;
        }

        Log.d(TAG, Arrays.toString(parsedData));

        boolean passed = false;
        int v1 = 0;
        int v2 = 0;
        if(parsedData[3].equals("S")) {
            passed = true;
            String values[] = parsedData[7].split("\\s+");
            v1 = Integer.parseInt(values[0].replaceAll("[\\D]", ""));
            v2 = Integer.parseInt(values[values.length-1]);
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, Arrays.toString(parsedData));
            String values[] = parsedData[5].split("\\s+");
            v1 = Integer.parseInt(values[0].replaceAll("[\\D]", ""));
            v2 = Integer.parseInt(values[values.length-1]);
        }
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        String currentDateandTime = sdf.format(new Date());
        String saveData =
                "Device: " + mConnectedDeviceName +
                        System.getProperty("line.separator") +
                        "Timestamp: " + currentDateandTime +
                        System.getProperty("line.separator") +
                        "Location: " + latitude + " (lat) / " + longitude + " (lon)" +
                        System.getProperty("line.separator") +
                        "Phone id: "  + telephonyManager.getDeviceId() +
                        System.getProperty("line.separator") +
                        "Valid:" + (passed ? "YES" : "NO") +
                        System.getProperty("line.separator") +
                        "Values: " + "T" + v1 + " / " + v2 +
                        System.getProperty("line.separator") +
                        "=========================" +
                        System.getProperty("line.separator");

        String csvData = mConnectedDeviceName + "," +
                currentDateandTime + "," +
                "\"http://maps.google.com/?q=" + latitude + "," + longitude + "\"," +
                "Valid: " + (passed ? "YES" : "NO") + " - " + "T" + v1 + " / " + v2 + Integer.toString(savedTaggantType) + "," +
                "\"" + telephonyManager.getDeviceId() + "\"" +
                System.getProperty("line.separator");

        ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.fragment_bluetooth_scanner, R.id.textView, saveData);
        mListView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
        mReadingLog.setText(saveData + mReadingLog.getText());
        mShowData.setText(saveData); //kg 8/25/17

        if(SP.getBoolean("writeToFile", true)) {
            writeToFile(saveData, csvData, true);
        }
    }
}
```

I have three xml files associated with this problem, but because of space I'll only include the one that contains the ListView and remove the other buttons.

```
view_list.xml contains the ListView:

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                  android:orientation="vertical"
                  android:id="@+id/viewList"
                  android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:paddingLeft="4dp"
            android:paddingRight="4dp"
            android:visibility="visible">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:id="@+id/listview_holder"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_alignTop="@id/button_holder"
                    android:layout_weight=".1"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">


                    <ListView
                        android:id="@+id/scanLogView"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:maxLines="4096"
                        android:scrollbars="vertical"
                        android:text="@string/app_name"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"/>

                </LinearLayout>

        </RelativeLayout>


    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: can you show fragment_bluetooth_scanner.xml ?

Comment: @NguyễnTrungHiếu sorry, I replied sooner but for some reason it didn't post.  I can't fit any more characters into the question box.  I figured out the error was with ArrayAdapter, specific with `this`, I made changes and there are no errors with building but it only adds one item to the list now.  I'm not sure what's happening but I opened a new question for this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was with ArrayAdapter.  I changed the decloration from

```
 ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
 R.layout.fragment_bluetooth_scanner, R.id.textView, saveData);
```

to

```
 ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
 android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, listItems);
```

It now builds the project and displays the listview.